# registration.php and enable custom module

Tags: magento2, module, custom, magento-2.1.2, component

I am new to Magento and PHP, and I am using Magento 2.1.2. I tried to create a new module as explained in http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-build-hello-world-magento-2-module-from-scratch. After creating the folders and files under app/code, and running php magento setup:upgrade, the first thing that is prompted, before the list of modules, is the code of my registration.php file. I don't know why this is happening; this is the first step before being able to see my module enabled.
I have Magento 2.1.2 installed over WAMP server, with sample data. Sample and admin page are working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `registration.php` file starts with `<?php`.
In the tutorial you linked the opening php tag is missing from the registration file, so php interprets this as an html file and just outputs the content.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code below:
use `\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar`;

```
 ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME,'<area>/<vendor>/<theme name>', __DIR__);
```

Where `<area>` is the functional area of the module (frontend, controller, and so on.), `<vendor>` is the name of the company providing the theme, and `<theme name>` is the name of the theme.